# Protractor with Typescript - How to understand which line test failed from Stack Trace?

Tags: typescript, selenium, protractor

We write protractor tests in Typescript.
Since selenium calls should be synchronous, pretty much every line in test starts with "await":

```
 var option = await element(by.cssContainingText('mat-option .mat-option-text', text));
        await browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(option), 10000);
        await option.click();
```

When the test fails - It is VERY hard to understand where exactly test failed at.
I understand that TS is transpiled to JavaScript, but there is no useful info in .js files as well, apart from the last file/method which failed.
For instance, if test calls checkbox.set() 20 times - how can I get which call failed?

The only useful info from stack trace below is this line:

```
at Function.<anonymous> (D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\src\utils\combobox-service.ts:15:23)
```

Rest of .js lines - are browser.js, promise.js , etc that don't help at all.
Here's stack trace example from out test:

```
Failures:
1) Gui Tests 177699 - Full Flow - With Import - T600MMSR
  Message:
    Failed: Wait timed out after 10002ms
  Stack:
    TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 10002ms
        at D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2201:17
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
        at D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27
        at D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
        at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    From: Task: <anonymous wait>
        at scheduleWait (D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2188:20)
        at ControlFlow.wait (D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2517:12)
        at Driver.wait (D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:934:29)
        at run (D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:59:33)
        at ProtractorBrowser.to.<computed> [as wait] (D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:67:16)
        at Function.<anonymous> (D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\src\utils\combobox-service.ts:15:23)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at fulfilled (D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\out_files\src\utils\combobox-service.js:4:58)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    From: Task: Run fit("177699 - Full Flow - With Import - T600MMSR") in control flow
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:94:19)
        at D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:64:48
        at ControlFlow.emit (D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\events.js:62:21)
        at ControlFlow.shutdown_ (D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2674:10)
        at D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2599:53
    From asynchronous test:
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\src\tests\guiTests.ts:1126:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Source\Fm\pmc\main\web\Automation\NovaFitAutomation\src\tests\guiTests.ts:847:1)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
```

Comment: Add some logging. The more the better. I use the `debug` package. That way I can configure what gets logged just by setting an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Logging is one way to go

Another option is to improve your code

`browser.wait` takes 3 parameters:

- condition as function
- timeout
- message on error

So if you do

```
await browser.wait(
  protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(option), 
  10000,
  'timeout waiting for element to be clickable ' + option.locator().toString()
);
```

This will tell what failed, and which element locator you used for that function to wait

Comment: Thanks. I already have a ton of logs. I also use message on error. didn't know about option.locator() though - will try to use it as well.

Comment: Stacktraces are a pretty fundamental part of debugging software. Logging has it's place, but sometimes you're going to get an error at some level where logs won't fully identify. Shouldn't need to log every single line.

Answer (score -1):

```
import {browser, ExpectedConditions as EC} from 'protactor';

await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(option), 10 * 1000,
 `${option} with ${option.locator().value} locator still not clickable after waiting for 10 seconds`);
```

Comment: Answers like this are not very helpful. There is no context to what you're suggesting, and it doesn't offer any specific to OPs questions around stacktraces.